# Does a non-mayor player get requests for public work projects?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Can a non-mayor user get public project requests or are these only given to the mayor?

My girlfriend and I play the game and she's the mayor, but I'm the one playing all the time with my second non-mayor user. I was wondering if I would get public project requests by villagers and have them later on the mayor's list to build them, or are these only given to the mayor?

What's the best way to get them requested quickly? Is it just random?

Comment: Next time, buy a copy of the game each. Mutual exclusion is never as fun as hoping between towns.

Answer (score 2):

Only the mayor can see and accept a public works projects. Though other villagers can help donate Bells to reach the project's goal, only the mayor can choose what project to work on.

Comment: I only wanted to know if the other players can get them requested...I guess I'll have to play on my gf's character if I want to progressany further with the town...

Comment: Non-mayor residents can indirectly request projects by talking to the mayor and telling them to build the project.

Comment: But he wants to know if the NPC residents can make requests to the non-mayor PC?

Comment: @Gwen Don't they occasionally tell the mayor about a random project? Such as, say, a yellow bench that wasn't available on the PWP list is now available because an NPC talked to the mayor and suggested it.

Comment: @Animal-Crosser But can the NPC talk to the non-mayor to request a project????????

Comment: @Gwen Ah, I didn't see where you said non-mayor PC. I doubt that would be the case, though, since non-mayor PCs wouldn't have any direct way of starting a project.

Answer (score -2):

No a non-mayor user can't get public works projects, requests are only given to the mayor.